# Does SO have a place to accumulate similar or duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am a student with quite limited experience in programming, so I spend a lot of time on SO. When I search for a problem I have, I usually come across multiple similar questions, some even duplicate. In my experience, duplicate questions may actually have a different answer, one of which works better than the other. Is there a place where issues for one topic (i.e Java JTables) are combined? I would also like if the answers are generalized because most of the time they focus on the code in the question. Is there maybe a way to integrate something like this in SO?

Comment: Very common problems do need about two dozen questions before SO users stop adding more of them.  Mission failed btw.  You don't have enough rep to really do anything about it and it is probably too late anyway to get them marked as duplicates.  Technically faq can be added to the tag wiki, you can propose an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I usually have to hack together different Questions and answers and
>   would like a place where I could share my results.

Above is from your comment. It's the crux of the issue. SO **requires users to do some work** to adapt generalised solutions (or specific applications of such) to their own problems. SO doesn't aim to do anyone's project for them. For the latter, there's an active marketplace outside  of SO for contracted work or code mentors.

This is intentional. SO can cater for and address a wider range of problems this way. If you would like to combine aspects across multiple Q&A and put them together in a coherent way, you *could* write your own Q&A. However, for this to be successful you should consider:

- For your Q&A to be more useful, someone should be able to apply the knowledge to their own problem rather than just *your* issue.
- If you are lifting aspects of other answers, you should credit them accordingly. Your answer should clearly demonstrate the novel way you are combining the various elements.

If your problem is trivial, it will likely be closed as a duplicate of trivial problems. (Remember, multiple duplicates may be associated with a single question.) Make sure you are contributing something new to SO. Use your judgement to assess whether it has some  use beyond your use case. You'll know after a few tries, via community feedback, whether you're getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do.

1. Add your answer to the open question. However, this will only work if your answer also answers the open question - which it should do if the questions are duplicate.
2. If you think that the duplicates aren't really duplicates then **edit** the question (you can suggest edits with any reputation) to bring out the differences and flag (or vote if you have enough reputation) to reopen. If your edit is accepted the question should be added to the reopen queue. While it normally takes 5 votes to reopen a question someone with a gold badge in one of the *original* tags on the question can reopen with a single vote.

   Once the question is reopend you can add your answer.

Comment: My issue is not with the duplicate questions or missing answers. I usually have to hack together different Questions and answers and would like a place where I could share my results.